# Python random Literal

Tags: python, python-typing

Given the following custom `Literal`:

```py
from typing import Literal, get_args

_ACTIONS = Literal["pasteCharAt", "copyCharAt", "deleteCharAt", "replaceCharAt",
                   "selectAll", "deleteAll", "copyAll", "pasteAllAt", "click",
                   "moveLeft", "moveRight"]
```

How can I generate random choice of its options?

For

```
print(f'random.choice(_ACTIONS) = {random.choice(_ACTIONS)}')
```

I got only:

```
  File "C:\python38\lib\random.py", line 288, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type '_GenericAlias' has no len()
```

And for the following attempt:

```
print(f'random.choice(list(_ACTIONS)) = {random.choice(list(_ACTIONS))}')
```

I also got an error:

```
  File "C:\python38\lib\typing.py", line 261, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\python38\lib\typing.py", line 685, in __getitem__
    params = tuple(_type_check(p, msg) for p in params)
  File "C:\python38\lib\typing.py", line 685, in <genexpr>
    params = tuple(_type_check(p, msg) for p in params)
  File "C:\python38\lib\typing.py", line 149, in _type_check
    raise TypeError(f"{msg} Got {arg!r:.100}.")
TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got 0.
```

I'm using Python 3.8.6, if this matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_args()` to convert the Literal to a tuple before attempting to use it with `random.choice()`. Here is an example:

```py
import random
from typing import Literal, get_args

_ACTIONS = Literal["pasteCharAt", "copyCharAt", "deleteCharAt", "replaceCharAt",
                   "selectAll", "deleteAll", "copyAll", "pasteAllAt", "click",
                   "moveLeft", "moveRight"]

# Convert Literal to a tuple
actions_tuple = get_args(_ACTIONS)

# Use random.choice with the tuple
print(f'random.choice(actions_tuple) = {random.choice(actions_tuple)}')

# Sample output:
# random.choice(actions_tuple) = replaceCharAt
```

This should give you a random choice from your defined `_ACTIONS` Literal.